# Como fazer o Footer ficar no rodapé após usar AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Já fiz várias aplicações e sempre utilizei o método abaixo para regular a altura do `footer`. Sempre utilizando Bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
     <div id="rodape">Hi-Nutrition 2014</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer .navbar{
  position: absolute !important;
}

#rodape{
  text-align:center;
  background:#a3a3a3;
  color:white;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Porém, dessa vez não está funcionando. Como poderia estar procedendo para manter meu footer no final da página?

Talvez o problema seja que nesse projeto eu estou trabalhando com o carregamento de uma `PartialView` via AJAX.

SCRIPT

```
 function Open(url) {
        Carregar();
        url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + url;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#corpoConteudo').html(response);
                $('#loader').remove();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Ocorreu um erro!');
                $('#loader').remove();
            }
        });
    }

    function Carregar() {
        $('#corpoConteudo').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
    }
```

Esse script carrega a `PartialView` para dentro da `<div id="corpoConteudo"></div>` e após esse elemento, estou chamando meu footer.

```
    <div class="container">
       <div id="corpoConteudo"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
       Hi-Nutrition 2014
    </div>
```

Ou seja, acredito que por carregar apenas uma parte do código, digamos, meu `container` com `position:relative` não empurra o rodapé para baixo.

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa tarde Rafael, você provavelmente se esqueceu (não sei usar linguagem técnica) mas, provavelmente deu branco e não lembrou que um `position:absolute` é sempre acompanhado de um encapsulador pai com `position:relative` e depois basta determinar para seu footer a propriedade `bottom:0` no CSS como demonstrei no exemplo que segue o link abaixo:

http://jsfiddle.net/okzo9a0y/

Coloquei um `height` para o exemplo no link mas de qualquer forma o seu `footer` independente se tiver propriedade no CSS ou não, estará sempre posicionado no fundo da sua página.

Abraços.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Fiz um teste fora do meu projeto e realmente funcionou. Porém, ao aplicar no meu escopo, tive problemas pelos motivos que acrescentei em minha postagem.

Comment: Se o footer não está sendo empurrado, será que os estilos estão abaixo da requisição AJAX? Inline por exemplo ou carregando só uma parte dos estilos?